# Prove that $c_V(X) \geq c_V(f(X))$ for $X>0$ and $f$ concave, positive, increasing,

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value, variance, jensen-inequality

I have a square-integrable random variable $X > 0$. Function $f : \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+  $ is concave, monotonically increasing and $f(0) = 0$.
I would like to prove that (and make sure that it is actually true):
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathbf{E}[X^2]}{\mathbf{E}[X]^2} \geq \frac{ \mathbf{E}[f(X)^{2}]}{ \mathbf{E} [f(X)]^2}
\end{equation}
Which is equivalent to saying that the coefficient of variation ($c_V$, CV) decreases after applying $f$ to $X$. Given of course that $\mathbf{E}[f(X)^{2}]$ and $\mathbf{E} [f(X)]$ exist.

It seems to be true numerically and this [Prove $\mathbf{E}[X^2] \geq \frac{ \mathbf{E}[X^{2\alpha}]}{ \mathbf{E} [X^{\alpha}]^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544581/prove-mathbfex2-geq-frac-mathbfex2-alpha-mathbfe-x-alp) seems to be a special case, but I can't come up with the analytical proof. It appears quite related to Jensen's inequality, but I can't use Hölder's inequality as in [Prove $\mathbf{E}[X^2] \geq \frac{ \mathbf{E}[X^{2\alpha}]}{ \mathbf{E} [X^{\alpha}]^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544581/prove-mathbfex2-geq-frac-mathbfex2-alpha-mathbfe-x-alp). Also, maybe the condition $f(0) = 0$ might not be needed for this to be true.
Thanks a lot of your help. Any leads would be highly appreaciated.